# Writing/Reading text online

Tags: c#, file-io, httpwebrequest, webclient

The title is rather inexplicit, but that’s because I’m open to almost any suggestions. Actually, I’m working on an XNA game project and I am working on implementing the possibility to choose a multiplayer game from a list of name. Typically, the datas I want to send should be a string of that kind :

```
   "ServerName;00.00.000.000"
```

For what I know, that can only be possible with a dedicated server (which is not an option I can consider) or by recording datas online somewhere it can be read by any clients. I’ve studied several possibilities but I only came up with failures. My first idea (and the ideal one) would be to – with a C# method – send datas to my website. I’ve read many things about WebClients and HttpWebRequest, but can’t seem to succeed. One thing I've tried, but which is totally done randomly since I have no idea how to use the WebClient class:

```
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.OpenWrite(@"http://www.myawsomewebsite/test.html")))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("COUCOU");
            writer.Flush();
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If you want to send some data to a Web page, that page has to be coded to accept the data and do something with it.

Comment: _a dedicated server (which is not an option I can consider)_ - if you can't consider a dedicated server on the grounds of cost, a VPS should be fine. That said, even the cost of virtualised Windows will be mainly licensing, so you may wish to consider a non-MS technology.

Comment: can you use ASP.NET or PHP or whatever on your website ?

Comment: @JimMischel Okay, could you explain what it means to be coded to accept data? Is is by using asp.NET or PHP ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula I guess I can use asp.NET or PHP, I don't really have any experience.. So in your opinion, I need to create a asp.NET or a PHP page in order to do what I need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this communication with server to be efficiend and fast you will need some sort of server side code (ASP.NET, PHP...). There is a ton of open source code and examples for PHP or ASP.NET to achieve this communication, maybe you event find product that you can use without any changes, so please do your googling :)

btw. if you still want to stick with `WebClient.OpenWrite` only then you can write to files trough FTP protocol, documentation for OpenWrite said it's supported :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7f52z4.aspx

but maybe better use FtpWebRequest

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144318.aspx

Comment: Thank you, that reallly helps. I'll be looking into it, even though I have no idea of how to use Asp.net or PHP...